# How to disable OpenCV debug logging in a C++ console application?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm coding a small interactive console app with C++ in which you can apply filters on images using `opencv`. The user can preview the image with the filters using this code:

```cpp
cv::Mat img; // image is loaded beforehand, filters may be applied

cv::imshow("Preview", img);
```

The `cv::imshow()` function triggers some logging in the background which is output to the console. I don't have any use of the logs and they take up a lot of space in the console, with which the user mainly interacts.

I'd rather not have that output at all. What's the best way to disable such console logging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenCV logging level can be set in the `cv::utils::logging` namespace:

```cpp
// First, add this necessary using
#include <opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp>

// Then the logging level can be set with the following function
cv::utils::logging::setLogLevel(cv::utils::logging::LogLevel::LOG_LEVEL_SILENT);
```

The logging level can of course also be set to any other level, adjusted to the use case.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the #include, and as a result, the logging namespace was not being found.  The #include fixed it.